# Преобразование HTML table в xls

Tags: php, excel, html, javascript

Добрый день, хочу получить excel документ из таблицы. Порылся в инете, нашел такого плана пример

```
<?php
$file="test.xls";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
?>
```

Работает, но выгружает весь сайт. А нужно 1 таблицу, реализация на php или js, какие идеи?

Comment: это пример чего? это как скачать файл с сайта вообщето...

Comment: Ну excel открывает корректно таблицу, остался вопрос как сохранить только таблицу из тела

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте ссылку "Скачать Excel", которая будет вести на отдельный скрипт, который будет генерить только искомую таблицу, с вышеозначенными заголовками.

Answer (score -1):

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);

$content = $client->request()->getBody();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?